# How to pass parameters to the Generic class constructor in c#.net?

Tags: c#, generics

```
public class SampleFile<Toriginal> 
{
    public SampleFile(File filename,string sname)
    {
    }
}
```

How to pass a values to `Samplefile` constructor?

Comment: It has nothing related to Generics, this will not compile as you declare a static parameter on a method

Answer (score 2):

`File` is a static class, you can't pass it as a parameter.

Change it to a `string`:

```
public class SampleFile<Toriginal> 
{
    public SampleFile(string filename,string sname)
    {
         //Here you can use File as it is static
         var lines = File.ReadAllLines(filename);
    }
}
```

Then just call it normally:

```
var sample = new SampleFile<Type>(@"c:\hi.txt", "bye.txt");
```